# How do you load a file into racket via command line?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have been trying to launch a racket program from the commandline (via 'racket') but have not been having success. According to the documentation (here http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/running-sa.html#%28part._mz-cmdline%29) passing `-f` followed by a file should evaluate that file. However, I can't seem to get this to work. As a test, I made the following file:

```
;test.rkt
#lang racket
(define a 1)
```

Then, running it in racket (supposedly loading the file) and attempting to recall the value of a:

```
racket -f test.rkt -i
Welcome to Racket v5.1.1.
> a
reference to undefined identifier: a
```

My end goal is to be able to launch a different program from a shell script using the `--main` option combined with loading the definitions with `-f` to start up execution, just have become a bit baffled since I can't seem to get this trivial bit working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `#lang racket` header from your file:

```
;test.rkt
(define a 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Figured it must be something simple - I'm so used to working in drracket it never occurred to me that could cause an issue.

Comment: I'd like to note that I do not delete my answer as the TL;DR version of Eli's below. But you should *really* be paying attention to him.

Comment: It's easy to do this in the shell without modifying the file: `racket -i -f <(tail -n +2 test.rkt)`

Answer (score 32):

Removing the `#lang` line works, but it means that your code is no longer a module, which makes it a pretty bad idea.  To start racket on a given module file, all you need is to just run `racket` on the file, nothing else is needed.  For example, put this in `test.rkt`:

```
#lang racket/base
(printf "Hi\n")
```

and just run it with `racket test.rkt`.  If you want to have command-line flags, you can use `(current-command-line-arguments)` to get a vector of additional command-line arguments, but there's also the [`racket/cmdline`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Command-Line_Parsing.html) library that makes it much easier to have standard kinds of flag processing.  Here's an example for that:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/cmdline)

(define excitedness "")
(define mode "Hi")
(command-line
  #:multi
  [("-e" "--excited") "add excitedness levels"
   (set! excitedness (string-append excitedness "!"))]
  #:once-each
  [("-b" "--bye") "turn on \"bye\" mode"
   (set! mode "Bye")])

(printf "~a~a\n" mode excitedness)
```

and you can now run it with `racket test.rkt <flags>`.  See also the Racket [Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/)'s [section on scripts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/scripts.html) for making your `test.rkt` even easier to run.

Finally, there is the `--main` approach that you've seen -- to use that, your module needs to provide a `main` function that receives all the command-line flags as arguments.  For example:

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/string)
(provide main)
(define (main . xs)
  (printf "You gave me ~s flags: ~a\n"
          (length xs) (string-join xs ", ")))
```

and to run it:

```
racket -t /tmp/y -m -- foo bar baz
```

The flag breakdown is: `-t` `require`s your module, `-m` causes racket to run your `main` function, and `--` means that the following flags are all passed to your program.  You can combine the flags like so:

```
racket -tm- /tmp/y foo bar baz
```

and that would be something that you'd usually put in your script trampoline as described in that guide section.

And, of course, this is all described in great details in [the reference manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/running-sa.html).

Comment: Hi, I'm confused, when I do `racket file.rkt` it is evaluated, but I want REPL so I do `racket file.rkt -i` but no REPL?!

Comment: If you want a REPL inside a module, start racket as usual, and then use [`enter!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/enter.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/enter..rkt%29._enter!%29%29).  Alternatively, use a nightly build with the new `xrepl` facility which gives you a more convenient `,enter` command.

Comment: Right now I use `enter!`, but I wanted to make a short-cut in Vim to evaluate and run REPL. Any idea?

Comment: I don't know much about vim -- but isn't the idea similar to vi, where you start the editor, write some code, then quit and run stuff in the shell?  For this mode of work, the new [XREPL](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/xrepl/) thing that I mentioned is useful -- you get an `,e` command that simply runs your `$EDITOR` on a given file, defaulting to the module you've entered into.

Comment: Yea, that is ideal to me, I am downloading the nightly build (although it was hard to find on racket-lang.org. I wonder wat was the usual workflow before XREPL? In vim you can execute shell commands (and interact with them) without exiting the editor. So you can set up it similar to DrRacket (Well, now that there is XREPL). I guess there should have been some workarounds before... Or maybe everyone is happy with DrRacket and don't need another editor.