# little schemer drracket error cannot reference an identifier before its definition

Tags: racket, the-little-schemer

beginner question,
just started the little schemer book and installed DrRacket on my macbook to try some of the code examples.

If I choose Racket language, the following code

```
 #lang Racket

(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))

(atom? '()) 



(define lat?
    (lambda (l)
        (cond
            ((null? l) #t)
            ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)) )
            (else #f))))
(lat? (a b))
```

will trigger error message:

```
a: unbound identifier in module in: a
```

if I choose R5RS language,

```
#lang R5RS

(define (atom? x)
  (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x))))

(atom? '()) 



(define lat?
    (lambda (l)
        (cond
            ((null? l) #t)
            ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l)) )
            (else #f))))
(lat? (a b))
```

I got an error message:

```
#%plain-module-begin: illegal use (not a module body) in: (#%plain-module-begin (module configure-runtime racket/base (require r5rs/init)) (define (atom? x) (and (not (pair? x)) (not (null? x)))) (atom? (quote ())) (define lat? (lambda (l) (cond ((null? l) #t) ((atom? (car l)) (lat? (cdr l))) (else #f)))) (lat? (a b)))
```

Anyone know what I did wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue going through the Little Schemer with racket, and found a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/6380648/390557 useful - basically, use `enter!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that last call should be

```
(lat? '(a b))
```

... no?

(Also: I would recommend using #lang racket in general, but I strongly suspect that your problem R5RS arises because you're "setting the language twice"; if you start your program with #lang R5RS, you don't need to change the language level. Conversely, if you set the language level, you shouldn't start your program with #lang R5RS. If you do both, I'm guessing you get the error message you saw.)